# Testing an Android app on an AVD with an API level lower than the target on Eclipse

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm developing my Android app with `target` set to 15, but would still like to test the app on lower API levels. When the 'Android Device Chooser' dialog opens however, AVDs with a level lower than 15 are not shown, even though the `minSdkVersion` is set to 10 in `AndroidManifest.xml`. How can I run my app on an API level 10 AVD?

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

In project.properties:

```
target=android-15
```

Comment: Have you created any AVDs with s lower API level?

Comment: Yes I have a list of them available in the AVD manager ranging from level 10 to 15.

Comment: Start the AVD first then when trying to run the app from eclipse it should either automatically use the one that's running or at least prompt you to use it.

Comment: @Squonk Yes! That did it. Please write that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Chishi : Glad to help - answer posted. I wasn't 100% sure as I rarely use AVDs but I thought I'd encountered something similar in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Converted from comment:*

Start the AVD first then, when trying to run the app from eclipse, it should either automatically use the one that's running or at least prompt you to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to SDK Manager and open the tab Android 2.3.3. Download the SDK Platform and the Intel x6 Atom System Image + Restart Eclipse!